# How to remove "Data" heading in PivotTable

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2010

I have a pivot table that is showing a heading that i didnt put in, the name is "Data" and i dont know how to remove it, because i can't find it anywhere.

As you can see in the images below the field isnt anywhere.

[image: PivotTable]
[image: Fields List]

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

That appears automatically when you have more than one item in your 'Values' column.

If you want to change it, you can use `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").DataPivotField.Caption = "Your Title for the Data"`